# Is it possible to disable "preinference" of typescript types?

Tags: typescript

Starting from ts 3.8 typescript is always preinference types on the compile-time, here is what I mean:

```
// typings.d.ts (our developer time module declaration)
declare module '@date-io/type' {
  export type DateType = unknown;
}

// myfile.d.ts (code)
export type Something = { date: DateType } 

// myfile.d.ts (declaration output)
export type Something = { date: unknown }
```

And it sounds completely reasonable, but in my case, it is required to keep `import('@date-io/type').DateType` in the declaration output. Because it should be declared when developers installing corresponding modules with their own `@date-io/type` declarations.

Is there any way to keep the typescript module import?

Comment: Honestly using module declaration to provide types into the library is hugely an antipattern. Please, use generics.

Comment: type aliases should be replaceable by the compiler  with their definition. You can use an interface. There is also a proposal for something like a forward type definition, but  that is not implemented yet